# Helloworld issue with React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having an issue getting my action to trigger successfully in a very very basic example.

All I want is to show/hide my state output.

When I click on the onClick text which triggers the dispatch, I get this error `Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`

Please view the repo here, `npm install` at root level and then run `webpack` inside the `simple` folder to bundle the example I'm stuck with (then open index.html, no server needed):

https://github.com/fuzzyrobot/reactTest

Comment: Take a look at `mapDispatchToProps` at **showAllContainer.js** really carefully. I think you should be able to just pass an object containing the action mapping there instead of a function. That could explain it.

Comment: Brilliant that fixes it! Any idea why though? What's the difference? If you make that an answer I can confirm it

Comment: There's a function form too by the looks of it. I'm guessing your original code didn't conform with the specification (returned functions over objects). I've always stuck with the object format myself as it's easy to manage. I'll set up an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `mapDispatchToProps` at **showAllContainer.js** really carefully. You can pass an object containing the action mapping there. That's often the easiest way to bind the actions to the dispatcher.

It would accept a function too. I think your definition didn't conform with [the specification](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options), though. That's why you received the error you did.